# Can I add a trailing item to a ListView in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter

I want to create a dynamic listview, with the last Item being a fixed 'trailing' item not related to the dynamic list.

For example this code

```
    class ListTest extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  ListTestState createState() => ListTestState();
}

class ListTestState extends State<ListTest> {
  var myList = ['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8','Item9',
    'Item10','Item11','Item12','Item13','Item14','Item15','Item16','Item17','Item18','Item19'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: <Widget> [Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(

              itemCount: myList?.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext content, int index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text(myList[index], ) );
              },
          ),
        ),
          Text("Trailing item not related to the list"),

        ] );
  }
}
```

generated this :-

[image]

What I want is the "Trailing item not related to the list" item to appear as if it were "Item20"!!

I've also experimented with `ListView.seperated` but I can't get this to work as I wish either.

Anyone have any ideas? I have a brain freeze.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```dart
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: myList?.length + 1,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext content, int index) {
                if(index == myList.length){
                return Text("Trailing item not related to the list");
                }
                return ListTile(title: Text(myList[index]));
              },
          ),
```

it will check if you are at the last item of the list and add the trailing `Widget`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's certainly unfrozen my brain. I was overthinking the problem. Very similar answer to Mohit's answer below but you both posted at pretty much the same time. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you were looking for

```
 class ListTest extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  ListTestState createState() => ListTestState();
}

class ListTestState extends State<ListTest> {
  var myList = ['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8','Item9',
    'Item10','Item11','Item12','Item13','Item14','Item15','Item16','Item17','Item18','Item19'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: <Widget> [Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(

              itemCount: myList?.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext content, int index) {
                return (index!=myList.length-1)?ListTile(title: Text(myList[index],):Container(/* The trailing widget you want to display*/) );
              },
          ),
        ),    
        ] );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's certainly unfrozen my brain. I was overthinking the problem. Very similar answer to Karim's answer above but you both posted at pretty much the same time. Appreciate your help